# I found my post on a different website. How should I proceed?

Tags: discussion, support

I asked a question here and now it is on a different website too. I can't edit the question there, and that could be a problem since there are other people's names on that code.

How to proceed?

Comment: I'll eat my ~/texmf if this is not an attempt at spamdexing.

Comment: It's not my intention, just don't know how to proceed. The post on this site has my username, like I had made it

Comment: You could report the site at https://tex.stackexchange.com/contact but sharing a link here is a bad idea, this will make the other site more attractive for search engines.

Comment: Oh thanks, I'll do this!

Comment: Related https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5962/a-website-importing-clone (which could also do with having the clone link removed).

Answer (score 6):

You are most likely looking at a SCRAPER of the site (different from a [clone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267/168244)). There would usually be no affiliation with Stack Exchange, but there should be some form of attribution for the content they post.

Read more about this and how it can be handled in this Meta.SE post:

- [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/168244)